# Summarize with the latest record for each group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Xdate = c("21-jul-2020", "29-jul-2020", "20-jul-2020", "13-may-2020" ),
                 names = c("peter", "lisa","peter", "lisa"),
                 score = c(1,3,5,7))
```

What is the most elegant way of getting the latest score out:

```
df_result <- data.frame(names = c("peter", "lisa"),
                        score = c(1, 3))
```

The latest score for peter is 1 and were achieved the `21-jul-2020`  and the latest score  by lisa is 3 and is achieved the `29-jul-2020`.

Comment: i am not sure i understand why you need to aggregate, if all you want is to read out the last score. could you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `slice_max()` in `dplyr`, which supersedes `top_n()` after version `1.0.0`, to select the most recent date.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Xdate = as.Date(Xdate, "%d-%b-%Y")) %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  slice_max(Xdate, n = 1) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   Xdate      names score
#   <date>     <chr> <dbl>
# 1 2020-07-29 lisa      3
# 2 2020-07-21 peter     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Xdate = as.Date(df$Xdate, "%d-%b-%Y")) %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  arrange(Xdate) %>%
  summarise_all(last)
## A tibble: 2 x 3
#  names Xdate      score
#  <chr> <date>     <dbl>
#1 lisa  2020-07-29     3
#2 peter 2020-07-21     1
```

A base R one-liner could be

```
aggregate(score ~ names, data = df[order(df$Xdate),], function(x) x[length(x)])
#  names score
#1  lisa     3
#2 peter     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one alternative from `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
    df$Xdate <- as.Date(df$Xdate, format = "%d-%b-%Y")
    df %>% 
        group_by(names) %>% 
        arrange(desc(Xdate)) %>% 
        mutate(names = first(names),
               score = first(score)) %>% 
        select(!Xdate) %>% 
        distinct(names, score)%>%
        ungroup()

# names score
# <fct> <dbl>
#1 lisa      3
#2 peter     1
```

or

```
df %>% group_by(names) %>% arrange(desc(Xdate)) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
```

or

```
df %>% group_by(names) %>% arrange(desc(Xdate)) %>% top_n(n = -1)
```

Comment: Thanks.. i also came up with something like this.. but there is no "one-liner-way" to do this??

Comment: @SorenStillingChristensen you can also try this

Answer (score 2):

Using `ave` in base R :

```
subset(transform(df, Xdate = as.Date(Xdate, "%d-%b-%Y")), 
                     Xdate == ave(Xdate, names, FUN = max))

#       Xdate names score
#1 2020-07-21 peter     1
#2 2020-07-29  lisa     3
```

With `transform` we first convert `Xdate` to date, using `ave` we get `max` date for each `names` and `subset` those values.